# Does Confluent's InfluxDB Sink Connector work with InfluxDB 2.0?

Tags: apache-kafka, influxdb, apache-kafka-connect, influxdb-2

Does Confluent's [InfluxDB Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-influxdb/influx-db-sink-connector/index.html) work with InfluxDB 2.0? If not, is there an alterative which does?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

It does not currently support InfluxDB 2.0, but I've been told it's on their roadmap. No estimated completion date. I ended up using 1.x instead. I'm not aware of any alternatives.

Comment: The alternative is to use telegraf Kafka input + influx 2 output